Java email client does not load emails from my Gmail account
I have following code (Spring Framework) to implement a service to load unread email from my Gmail account.
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
public void readEmails() {
    // TODO: load contact emails from database
    List<ContactEmailAccount> ContactEmailAccounts = List.of(
            new ContactEmailAccount("imap.gmail.com", "zhazi@mycompany.com", "abc@123")
    );

    for (ContactEmailAccount account : ContactEmailAccounts) {
        executorService.submit(() -> fetchEmails(account));
    }
}

@Async
public void fetchEmails(ContactEmailAccount account) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", account.getServiceProviderHost());
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", IMAP_PORT);
    System.out.println("www -> Reading emails from " + account.getUsername());

    try {
        Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);
        emailSession.setDebugOut(System.err);  // Change debug output to System.err
        emailSession.setDebug(true);
        Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
        System.out.println("Connecting to IMAP store...");
        store.connect(account.getServiceProviderHost(), account.getUsername(), account.getPassword());
        System.out.println("Connected to IMAP store.");
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        System.out.println("Opening Inbox folder...");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        if (!emailFolder.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Folder does not exist!");
            return;
        }

        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("www -> Total messages in INBOX: " + messages.length);
        for (Message message : messages) {
            EmailRequest emailRequest = new EmailRequest();
            emailRequest.setSenderEmail(message.getFrom()[0].toString());
            emailRequest.setReceiverEmail(message.getAllRecipients()[0].toString());
            emailRequest.setReceivedTimestamp(LocalDateTime.parse(message.getReceivedDate().toString()));
            emailRequest.setMessageId(message.getHeader("Message-ID")[0]);
            emailRequest.setInReplyTo(message.getHeader("In-Reply-To") != null ? message.getHeader("In-Reply-To")[0] : null);
            emailRequest.setReferences(message.getHeader("References") != null ? new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(message.getHeader("References"))) : null);
            emailRequest.setEmailBody(message.getContent().toString());
            System.out.println("www -> email received " + emailRequest.getEmailBody());
            // Add attachments if needed

            kafkaTemplate.send(KAFKA_TOPIC_EMAIL_INCOMING, emailRequest);
        }

        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error while connecting to IMAP store: " + e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

However, there is no emails loaded. To see where the issue is, I put many logs in the code, but I only see the log below:

www -> Reading emails from zhazi@mycompany.com

nothing else, not even "Connecting to IMAP store...".
Please note

I enabled the "IMAP" option from my Gmail account.
There are two new emails sitting in my email inbox.
I think the connection is OK. Cause when I run "telnet imap.gmail.com 993", I got
   (base) [~]  $ telnet imap.gmail.com 993
   Trying 142.251.2.109...
   Connected to imap.gmail.com.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   Connection closed by foreign host.




It doesn't print any logs, but does it finishes or just stuck on something. In first case you may change Exception to Throwable in catch block. In latter case you need thread dump.

Commonly, these days, password auth won't work. You need oauth or better still an application password generated in Google's dev console

Enable debug logging (see the JakartaMail/AngusMail documentation for details).

I figured it out by myself. Below is for those guys who might encounter the same problem. There are two issues here:

I used a wrong dependency
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>



The error was burried in the lib code. When I debug, I can see a ClassNotFound error captured in the lib. The correct dependency should be
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency> 


Once I used the correct dependency, The error was clear - bad crendentials. It turns out that the personal password (used to log in gmail) cannot be used for an email client.
As of Google's current security policies, there are only two main methods to access Gmail programmatically:


App Passwords (if two-factor authentication (2FA) is enabled on the account)
OAuth2 (recommended by Google as the most secure method)"

So either approach, the personal password cannot be directly used

(Which is what I'd already told you)

I would recommend to add everything in try catch block so that you'll get proper logs to check out if any error. add e.printStackTrace(), and add SYSouts for the e.getMessage(). as I think your not debugging, if you are debugging also there might be some issues in the Libraries which your using. So try to use try catch for all the code I would recommend.

In my opinion, your answer does not provide a solution but rather some suggestions for how the OP can isolate the cause of his problem. I believe that one should post an answer only when it solves the problem described in the question. Therefore, I feel that your answer is more a comment than an answer. By the way, I did not down-vote your answer.
